# Accessing env variables in config files in Next.js on the client side in production

Tags: typescript, next.js, environment-variables, i18next

So I am using next-i18next and in the config file I set some parameters using env variables:

```
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        defaultLocale: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEFAULT_LOCALE
    }
}
```

In local development this seems to work fine, however in production I am not seeing this variable in the browser(client side) (when debugging in devtools `NEXT_PUBLIC_DEFAULT_LOCALE` is `undefined`) and thus in the production on the client side I am not getting the correct settings loaded.

Any idea why env variable in Next.js is not being exposed in the client side to the js config file(`next-i18next.config.js`)? Is there some specific way to load env variables into the js config files in Next.js? I am using Typescript for the components and packages.

Comment: How many env files do you have and what are their names?

Comment: @Matt so I have .env.local, .env.template and env.test also I have some env variables set in `next.config.js` in publicRuntimeConfig (but they are coming from .env.template when deployed)

Comment: My guess would be that your env.template is not being loaded as its not a supported name from memory? for production use .env.production and then for dev use .env.development - I may be way off course here but without seeing your project that would be my first guess